# How to useState to update mutiple items in an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

```
let initialData =   [
{ id: 1, value: "EXPLORER", status:false, name:'explorer'},
{ id: 2, value: "YIDINJI-ADMIN", status:false, name:'yidinji' }]

  let [data,setData] = useState(initialData)
```

The above give data is my initial state of array, Sometimes I have to update multiple items using a single map function

```
    let newData =  await data.map(item => {
      (item.id === 1)? {...item, status : true} : item;
      (item.id === 2)? {...item, status : true} : item;
    })

    setData(newData)
```

I have tried multiple ways to update the status of two data in a single map function, but nothing is working. Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `return` in `map`. Just add `return` like this:

```
let newData = await data.map((item) => {
  return item.id === 1 ? { ...item, status: true } : item;
});

setData(newData);
```

Update, if you want update multyiple items, you can do like this:

```
let newData = await data.map((item) => {
  let result = item;
  if (item.id === 1 || item.id === 2) {
    result = { ...item, status: true };
  }
  return result;
});

setData(newData);
```

Comment: but return, will allow me to only update one, Since i want to update multyiple items

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. You forgot to return **item**.

```js
let newData = data.map(item => {
    
      if (item.id === 1 || item.id===2){
      item.status=true
      }
      return item
    })
```

Comment: You welcome. I am happy that this helped you